# Solution for the Second order ODE with Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> $$ \begin{cases} v''(t)-v(t)=f(t) & 0<t<h\\ v(0)=0=v(h) \end{cases},
>  $$ where $f\in L^{2}$.

Is there a explicit solution of integral form?

---

For the case of 
$$
v''(t)-v(t)=0,
$$
 the solution is $v(t)=C_{0}e^{t}+C_{1}e^{-t}$ for constants $C_{0},$
$C_{1}$. But I can't go further with the general nonhomogenous term
$f(t)$.

Comment: Do you know about Green's functions?

Comment: @Chappers No. Is this related to that?

Comment: Yes, Green's functions are used to solve a nonhomogeneous differential equation with specified boundary conditions and a general function on the right hand side.

Comment: The solution will be the same as the variation of parameters one (although possibly in a different form), but the technique is much more general than just the second-order ODEs variation of parameters is normally used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the solutions of the associated homogeneous problem
$$y_1(t)=\sinh(t),y_2(t)=\sinh(t-h),$$
satisfying $y_1(0)=y_2(h)=0$. Variation of parameters gives some particular solutions:
$$v(t)=\sinh(t)\int_{t_1}^t \frac{-\sinh(\tau-h)f(\tau)}{\sinh(h)} \mathrm{d} \tau+ \sinh(t-h)\int_{t_2}^t  \frac{\sinh(\tau) f(\tau)}{\sinh(h)} \mathrm{d} \tau .$$
In order to satisfy the boundary condition $v(0)=0$ we take $t_2=0$, and in order to satisfy $v(h)=0$ we take $t_1=h$.